# How get the shortest path

Tags: ionic-framework, shortest-path, ng-map

Am using ionic and firebase to develop my project.I use ngmap to display the events but I would display the shortest path to the event location. Can you provide me by a useful link or exemple please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-map show the best way between two points (waypoints)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036541/ng-map-show-the-best-way-between-two-points-waypoints)

Comment: This question is too broad and has been asked before (with an answer).